# Adjust datalabel to specific position (HIGHCHARTS)

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I want to set a datalabel for the VALUE to  RIGHT of the bar, and the value of the SERIES (in my case "bar1, bar2, bar3") that are always at the LEFT of the bar. as it is in the picture.[image]

this is my code

http://jsfiddle.net/pb1q9wzk/

```
plotOptions: {
 bar: {
   dataLabels: {
   padding: 0,
   allowOverlap: true,
   enabled: true,
   align: 'left',
   color: '#FFFFFF',
   inside: true,
   crop: false,
   overflow: "none",
   formatter: function() {            
    return this.series.name + " " + this.y;                       
  },
  style: {
    width:100
  }                       
.
.
.
```

Comment: In the highcharts you cannot print double datalabels, so better is return number in datalabel and then use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) to add missing labels (like series.name)

Comment: @SebastianBochan 
excuse my ignorance , I do not understand and do not know how to do what you say.

Comment: Let me know which parts are unclear  ?

Comment: @SebastianBochan how I can use a text renderer to put in all categories?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I have tried many things, but does not work me. can you help me please?

Comment: @SebastianBochan no matter the method, I just want to display the text "bar" on the left bar, and the result set to the right of the bar. so as I have in the picture.

Comment: Could you recreate example which doesn't work with renderer ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100772/discussion-between-o11ce-and-sebastian-bochan).

Comment: @SebastianBochan I read of "render" is to put a text, but would remain outside the category.

Answer (score 0):

Just increase your `align: right` in `plotOptions`.

I hope this will solve your problem.

```
 plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                padding:0,
                allowOverlap:true,
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'right',
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    inside: true,
                    crop: false,
                    overflow:"none",
                        formatter: function() {

                    return this.series.name+ " "+ this.y;

                    console.log(this.series.name);
                },
```