# align text on the left and the right in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I want to set the `VALUE` to `RIGHT` of the bar, and the value of the SERIES (in my case `bar1, bar2, bar3`) that are always at the `LEFT` of the bar. as it is in the picture.

[image]

this is my code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pb1q9wzk/)

```
plotOptions: {
bar: {
dataLabels: {
padding: 0,
allowOverlap: true,
enabled: true,
align: 'left',
color: '#FFFFFF',
inside: true,
crop: false,
overflow: "none",
formatter: function() {            
  return this.series.name + " " + this.y;                       
},
style: {
  width:100
}                       
.
.
.
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/bar-datalabels-align-inside-bar/

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34782508/adjust-datalabel-to-specific-position-highcharts?noredirect=1#comment57352882_34782508

Comment: @SebastianBochan i need help...please..

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting align of axis labels to left and enabling the data labels. 
See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/euot9L66/1/

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'bar'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Bar 1', 'Bar 2', 'Bar 3'],
      labels: {
        align: 'left',
        x: 5
      }
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [52, 90, 42]
    }]
  });
});
```

Comment: Madhav, Did this help?